# Memory leaks occur if exit(exitcode) in C?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, exit, exit-code

In C program, if there are dynamically allocated memories remained not freed after the execution of the program exit with `exit(100);`, do we get memory leaks problem? For example:

```
int main (void) {
    char str1[] = "Hello World"
    char *str2;
    str2 = malloc(strlen(str1 + 1));

    if (str2) 
        exit(101); // memory leaks?

    free(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may depend on your OS, but the answer is No

Comment: The OS will likely not. Your *process* does, for that brief moment before it actually terminates. I'm guessing the whole termination-thing is probably a much bigger problem you're going to be concerned with, however.

Answer (score 4):

Not under modern operating systems, no. The OS automatically collects all the memory when the process dies.

In fact freeing memory can actually be detrimental for the performance if the program is exiting anyway. The reason is that calling `free` sometimes involves a lot of work - updating a lot of structures, touching cache lines etc. By simply exiting you don't do all this userspace nonsense and the OS takes care of actually unmapping your data.

Comment: But it's still bad practice to do so.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's not bad practice really. I remember a post by R.. where he advocated one shouldn't free memory right before exiting.

Comment: I'm wondering what the reasoning is. If R.. wrote that, it must be true, but I don't see how this is *not* a conceptual problem.

Comment: @H2CO3 Well it makes a lot of sense if you think about what memory allocation using `malloc` is. The real memory allocation is done by the OS, and it will do its own "freeing" when the process is done. Your own `free`s are valid strictly inside your process which is dying anyway. So why bother ?

Comment: @cnicutar Theoretically, given that the system has enough free memory, and we know the program won't eat up too much memory during its session, we don't even need to worry about freeing memory then?

Comment: @JaneBerman What I'm saying is that if you decide to exit just do it and stop bothering about `free`. If you decide to linger on and the memory is unnecessary, then by all means `free` it.

Comment: @H2CO3 R.. isn't always right.  He might be in this case though.  If your program spends ages cleaning up memory just before quitting, it might be considered a bad user experience.

Comment: Another point: in complex, multithreaded apps, explicitly freeing such memory in a safe way is almost impossible and, if you try to do it, a huge amount of explicit thread-shutdown code is required.  Such code is difficult and prone to failure, as the thousands of 'how to stop my thread' posts here testify.  The OS can easily stop all process threads running on all cores before releasing memory and other resources they may be using, user code cannot.

Comment: @MartinJames Excellent point. I haven't thought about cases where freeing is simply hard to code.

Answer (score 1):

All dyanmically allocated memory allocated using `malloc` needs to be freed explicitly by calling `free`.  While your program keeps running the memory unallocated this way might be called a leak(*provided it is not being used at all*).However, once your program/process returns the OS simply reclaims the memory it allocated to the process. The OS does not understand ***leak*** it simply reclaims back what it gave to the process.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the operating system. All modern operating systems (to my knowledge) will free memory not explicitly freed by the C program when it has completed execution. Thus, you can get away with this without consequences under normal circumstances. In fact, there are some schools of thought that do not recommend releasing memory when program execution will end soon as it is unnecessary. However, if you happen to be dealing with old or unusual operating systems that can be dangerous. In some of those systems, it can take a restart to free the memory again.